# Atomically figuring out if a handler has subscribers

Tags: c#, atomic

Right now, I am using the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` method in order to check if we are on the right thread, as well as if there are any subscribers to an event handler. If both of these conditions are true, the event will be fired off. I do this with the following code:

```
Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref MyEventHandler, null, null)?.Invoke(this, MyArguments);
```

This works pretty nicely for me. However, here is what I would like to know. Is there any way to refactor this statement so that I can return a boolean, indicating whether or not there were any subscribers to the `MyEventHandler`?

-- Edit --

I would also like to keep the same functionality of firing the event (if the conditions are satisfied) *along with* being able to know whether or not there were any subscribers to the handler.

-- Edit 2 --

Re-reading this myself, I think it could be worded a little better. Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Check if we are on the right thread.
2. Check for subscribers.
3. Fire the event if conditions 1 and 2 are satisfied.
4. Assign a boolean as true if there were subscribers, false if there were not

Comment: Your existing code invokes the eventhandler if it's not null.  That is all it does.  I don't understand why you are using CompareExchange here - is this for non-x86 or non-Windows platforms?

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/

Comment: @hoodaticus No, and no!

Comment: Declaring the MyEventHandler field as volatile and using Skeet's first example with the handler local variable is faster, just FYI.  CompareExchange can take a bus lock.

Comment: What do you want to do if you are not on the right thread?

Comment: This page [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx#code-snippet-4) seems to indicate that `Interlocked` may be unnecessary since the `null conditional operator` _"is thread-safe because the compiler generates code to evaluate PropertyChanged one time only, keeping the result in temporary variable."_ (@JonSkeet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var handler = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref MyEventHandler, null, null);
var hasSubscribersAndOnRightThread = handler != null &&
    handler.GetInvocationList().Any(h => h != null) && AmIOnTheRightThread();

if (hasSubscribersAndOnRightThread) handler.Invoke(this, MyArguments);
```

I don't see any race conditions here that require more than that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this works better if you ask questions in the comments. :)

Comment: And to answer your question, no there isn't anything missing from my question.